# iterate an array and collect specific data at any match of and additionally provided property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
var data2 = {
  "name" : "history",
  "list": [{
    "type" : "a",
    "max" : 52.346377,
    "min" : 0.1354055,
    "date": "17-01-01",
    "time": "21:38:17"
  }, {
    "type" : "b",
    "max" : 55.3467377,
    "min" : 0.1154055,
    "date": "17-01-01",
    "time": "22:38:17"
  }, {
    "type" : "b",
    "max" : 48.3467377,
    "min" : -0.1354055,
    "date": "17-01-01",
    "time": "23:38:17"
  }]
}
```

I'd like to be able to iterate this data's `list` property and check if a list item's `type` value matches another provided value. Then if so, I'd like to collect the `max` and `min` values.

How could one achieve this task? I do not know how to figure this one out.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the code what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you add the output which you want, and what you tried

Comment: note to everyone ... the OP just stated elsewhere *"... I wanted all the max and min values for a particular value of type, not the absolute max and absolute min. Any way to include this?"*

Comment: ... does any of the given answers still miss an acceptance criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Use filter on data.list will only deliver those objects whose type is identical to the searched value. Afterwards using map to create new objects with the min/max-values.

```js
function filterArray(array, value) {
   let result = array.list.filter( obj => obj.type===value).map( filtered => {
       return {max: filtered.max, min: filtered.min}
   });
   return result;
}

var data2 = {
  "name" : "history",
  "list": [
  {
      "type" : "a",
      "max" : 52.346377,
      "min" : 0.1354055,
      "date": "17-01-01",
      "time": "21:38:17"
    },
    {
      "type" : "b",
      "max" : 55.3467377,
      "min" : 0.1154055,
      "date": "17-01-01",
      "time": "22:38:17"
    },
    {
      "type" : "b",
      "max" : 48.3467377,
      "min" : -0.1354055,
      "date": "17-01-01",
      "time": "23:38:17"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(filterArray(data2,'b'));
console.log(filterArray(data2,'a'));
console.log(filterArray(data2,'any'));
```

Comment: you can not be sure at all if this is exactly what the OP really wants. As the Q was ask, one also can assume a simple `filter` and `map` which would result in a list of objects that just feature min/max properties

Comment: @Peter Seliger You are right, but the OP didn't answering till now what the desired output is. So I suppose as best I can to get a possible solution. For this I described it short. If the OP wants anything else than he can tell us so. Editing an answer to new requests is allways possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for helping me out. Sorry I forgot to say that I wanted all the max and min values for a particular value of type, not the absolute max and absolute min. Any way to include this?

Comment: No problem as Peter Seliger mentioned it was not really clear what you want so I assume something and this is not allways what the OP wants. I edited it to your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for ... of` loop for example;

```js
let checkType = "a";
let max, min;

for (let entry of data2.list) {
   if (entry.type === checkType) {
      max = entry.max;
      min = entry.min;
      break;
   }
}

console.log(min, max);
```

Now let's beware this will stop at the first occurence of the right "type" (in case you have multiple entries with the same type);

If you want to account for multiple entries of the same "type", you could combine a `filter` and `map` iteration, for example :

```js
let checkType = "b";
let minMaxValues = data2.list
                   .filter(e => e.type === checkType)
                   .map(e => { min : e.min, max : e.max });

console.log(minMaxValues);
/*
[{
  min : 0.1154055,
  max : 55.3467377
},
{
  min : -0.1354055,
  max : 48.3467377
}] */
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I wanted all the max and min values for a particular value of type, not the absolute max and absolute min. Any way to include this?"*

The probably most natural/obvious approach was to first [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) any list item of a provided matching `type` ...

```
data2.list.filter(item => item.type === typeToCheckFor)
```

... and in a second step to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) any item of the filtered array ...

```
.map(item => { min: item.min, max: item.max });
```

Another approach was to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the result within one iteration cycle ...

```js
var data2 = {
  "name" : "history",
  "list": [{
    "type" : "a",
    "max" : 52.346377,
    "min" : 0.1354055,
    "date": "17-01-01",
    "time": "21:38:17"
  }, {
    "type" : "b",
    "max" : 55.3467377,
    "min" : 0.1154055,
    "date": "17-01-01",
    "time": "22:38:17"
  }, {
    "type" : "b",
    "max" : 48.3467377,
    "min" : -0.1354055,
    "date": "17-01-01",
    "time": "23:38:17"
  }]
}


function collectMinMaxValuesOfMatchingType(collector, item) {
  if (item.type === collector.type) {

    collector.list.push({
    //type: item.type,
      min: item.min,
      max: item.max
    })
  }
  return collector;
}


console.log(
  data2.list.reduce(collectMinMaxValuesOfMatchingType, {
    type: 'b',
    list: []
  }).list
);
console.log(
  data2.list.reduce(collectMinMaxValuesOfMatchingType, {
    type: 'a',
    list: []
  }).list
);

console.log(
  data2.list.reduce(collectMinMaxValuesOfMatchingType, {
    type: 'foo',
    list: []
  }).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```